# Combine Data in Multiple Rows into Single Row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with information about people (Name, HP No., Home No., Email etc). However, they are in different rows, and not all rows have all information.

How do I combine all information about one person into a single row?

Current

[image]

Desired

[image]

Comment: Are the duplicate records always guaranteed to be duplicate but potentially incomplete information, or could there ever be a difference in content?

Comment: There will not be difference in content, just duplicate content in different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using VBa

```
Sub Pirates()

Range("F:I").Cells.Clear

'first, copy the headers

Range("F1").Value = Range("A1").Value
Range("G1").Value = Range("B1").Value
Range("H1").Value = Range("C1").Value
Range("I1").Value = Range("D1").Value

'now, to work out the content

Dim row As Integer
row = 2

Dim resultRow As Integer
resultRow = 2

Dim previousName As String
    previousName = Range("A" & row).Value


Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Dim currentName As String
    currentName = Range("A" & row).Value

    If (currentName <> previousName) Then
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
        previousName = currentName
    End If

        If Range("A" & row).Value <> "" Then
            Range("F" & resultRow).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        End If

        If Range("B" & row).Value <> "" Then
            Range("G" & resultRow).Value = Range("B" & row).Value
        End If

        If Range("C" & row).Value <> "" Then
            Range("H" & resultRow).Value = Range("C" & row).Value
        End If

        If Range("D" & row).Value <> "" Then
            Range("I" & resultRow).Value = Range("D" & row).Value
        End If

        row = row + 1



Loop

End Sub
```

This is what my Excel looked like

[image]

And after I run the above macro

[image]

As you can see, I chose to add the results it to the side of the initial table, as it's non-destructive

Answer (score 1):

This Macro will fill any blank cells with correct information if it's populated on any of the rows. You may then use advanced filter to copy unique rows.

```
Sub CopyData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long

rownum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
colnum = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:AAA1"))


For i = 2 To rownum
    For j = 1 To colnum
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) = False Then
            For k = 1 To rownum
                If Trim(Cells(k, 1)) = Trim(Cells(i, 1)) Then
                    Cells(k, j) = Cells(i, j)
                End If
            Next k


        End If
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Dave's approach is cleaner and doesn't affect the original data, but this is an alternative if you'd like.